# Point of try catch finally blocks?

Tags: c#, try-catch, try-catch-finally

What is the difference between using finally

```
void ReadFile(int index)
{
    // To run this code, substitute a valid path from your local machine
    string path = @"c:\users\public\test.txt";
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
    char[] buffer = new char[10];
    try
    {
        file.ReadBlock(buffer, index, buffer.Length);
    }
    catch (System.IO.IOException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error reading from {0}. 
           Message = {1}", path, e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            file.Close();
        }
    }
    // Do something with buffer...
}
```

and not using it?

```
void ReadFile(int index)
{
    // To run this code, substitute a valid path from your local machine
    string path = @"c:\users\public\test.txt";
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
    char[] buffer = new char[10];
    try
    {
        file.ReadBlock(buffer, index, buffer.Length);
    }
    catch (System.IO.IOException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error reading from {0}. 
            Message = {1}", path, e.Message);
    }

    if (file != null)
    {
        file.Close();
    }

    // Do something with buffer...
}
```

Comment: The catch block might rethrow the error, raise a new one etc, which will bypass the close out of finally. See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618/what-is-the-point-of-the-finally-block

Comment: I know someone else will type out an answer faster than I can but have you considered causing an IOException and seeing the difference for yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The former example will run `file.Close()` regardless of whether an exception is thrown or what exception is thrown.

The latter will only run if no exception is thrown or if a `System.IO.IOException` is thrown.

Comment: yeah I couldn't then, wasn't on 'til now.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that if you don't use `finally` and an exception other than `IOException` is thrown your application will be leaking a file handle because the `.Close` line will never be reached.

Personally I always use [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) blocks when dealing with disposable resources such as streams:

```
try
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(@"c:\users\public\test.txt"))
    {
        char[] buffer = new char[10];
        reader.ReadBlock(buffer, index, buffer.Length);
         // Do something with buffer...
    }
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error reading from {0}. Message = {1}", path, e.Message);
}
```

This way I don't have to worry about properly disposing them. The try/finally stuff is handled by the compiler and I can focus on the logic.

Comment: yeah I just copied and pasted an example, what if I didn't specify down to just IOExceptions?

Answer (score 1):

Your catch block may throw an exception itself (consider the situation when `path` is null-reference). Or the exception thrown in `try` block is not `System.IO.IOException`, so it is not handled. File handle will not be closed in both cases unless `finally` used.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, nothing. If you let the exception be thrown out of the catch block, then the finally part would run, but the other variation wouldn't.