# Does `using` dispose all the the objects declared in it?

Tags: c#

I wonder if the object created in the `using`statement gets disposed if I perform a `return` or `throw` operation. Example as follows.

```
using(SomeClass thing = new SomeClass())
{
  ...
  if(condition)
    return;
  ...
}
```

Will the above get confused or is GC to be trusted here?

Comment: Absolutely, that's the whole point of introducing a `using` block in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it will.  The `using` statement will result in a `finally` block being created.  A `finally` block's code will be run even if an exception is thrown in the related `try` block, or if there is a `return` statement in that try block.

There are only a few exceptions that can cause a `finally` block's code to not be executed, and they are all listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10260233/1159478), but my guess is that in your situation you'll be able to live with those consequences.

Answer (score 2):

`using` is the equivalent of `try-finally` so, yes, it does.

Answer (score 2):

dispose if it is implemented will always get called.  Its the equivalent of calling dispose in a finally block.

Answer (score 2):

It will dispose, yes. It will create a finally block in the CIL code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because using is extended into a try finally by the compiler. The dispose will occur inside the finally block. Also, the finally will contain a test to check if the variables in the using are null (in case there are exceptions on the constructors).

Answer (score 2):

When writing a using statement:

```
using(SomeClass thing = new SomeClass())
{
    //...
    if (condition)
        return;
    //...
}
```

this will result in the following code:

```
SomeClass thing;
try
{
    thing = new SomeClass();
    //...
    if (condition)
        return;
    //...
}
finally
{
    if(thing != null)
    {
        thing.Dispose();
    }
}
```

So all object declared `using ( /* HERE */ )` will get disposed automatically. Objects declared inside the `{}` won't.
But you can of course nest (or stack) using statements:

```
using (var thing = new SomeClass())
    using (var another = new Another())
        using (var somethingElse = new Whatever())
        {
            //...
        }
```

which in turn of course is just the syntactic sugar for writing

```
using (var thing = new SomeClass())
{
    using (var another = new Another())
    {
        using (var somethingElse = new Whatever())
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

because when a statement is followed by just one block of code (in this case another `using`-block) you can skip the curly braces...

When using two or more objects of the same type you can chain the declaratio within the `using`-statement:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(), stream2 = new MemoryStream())
{
    //...
}
```

(Thanks to @Gratzy for pointing that out)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the question does not match with the details, and the details have been addressed here a bunch but not the title question...

> Does `using` dispose all the the objects declared in it?

**NO**, it does not. It only calls `Dispose()` for the object(s) in its declaration. It does not call `Dispose()` for *objects declared in it*.

I usually see this kind of thing in code

```
using(var sqlConn = new SqlConnection("connStr"))
using(var sqlCmd = new SqlCmd("CmdText", sqlConn))
{
   sqlConn.Open();
   var reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
   while (reader.Read())
   {
     //stuff is done
   }
}
```

This will dispose and close both `sqlConn` and `sqlCmd` when the scope is complete for those but the `reader` that was *declared in the using scope* does not have `Dispose()` automatically called for it .

Comment: It's a great answer. Thanks. However, I wonder if you could elaborate on the mismatch between the message title and the details. I reread it and to me it appears obvious how they correlate. But it's **my** question so it might be more clear in **my** mind (filling some blanks ninja style) than in **yours**. I'll gladly alter the formulations if I only know what and how.

Comment: @KonradViltersten - The reader in my example is declared and instantiated inside the using block - "declared **in it**"  as your title says.  The rest of your question describes the variables that are **part** of the using statement declaration. This could be also be considered as "in it" but I dont because its not "inside it". HTH

Comment: Sorry, I had to deaccept your answer. Apparently, @servy feels that the edit doesn't comply with my original intention. Sorry to have caused commotion.

Comment: @KonradViltersten - no need to apologize to me for un-accepting the answer. Either interpretation could have been valid, I just wanted to make sure that both were represented here.