# Python Flask, redirect after rendering a template

Tags: python, html, css, flask, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a user after a template has been rendered. Essentially, my code waits till a variable turns to False, and then redirects the user. The code renders a loading animation and tells the user to wait. The code renders the html and css template, but then when the wait is over doesn't redirect the user to a new url. My code:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template
import json
import requests
import webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

global is_busy
is_busy = False


app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='template')


@app.route('/')
def main_menu():
    return redirect(url_for('enteruserid'))


@app.route('/EnterID')
def enteruserid():
    global is_busy
    return render_template('enterid.html')
def waitUntil(condition, output):
    time.sleep(1)


@app.route('/Scrape', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
   global is_busy
   if request.method == 'POST':
      id = request.form['nm']
      try:
          int(id)
          return render_template('waitingscreen.html')
          waitUntil(is_busy, False)
          return redirect(url_for('scrapingtheinternet', target_id=id))
      except:
          return redirect(url_for('notanint'))
   else:
      id = request.args.get('nm')


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

This code doesn't include the function where the "Scraping" occurs.

enterid.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DCF</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="Reverse image search discord user id's">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Discord">
        <style>
            h1 {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                color: #2f2d2d;
                text-align: Center;
            }
            p {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                text-align: Center;
                color: #2f2d2d;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action = "http://localhost:5000/Scrape" method = "post">
          <h1>Reverse Image Search</h1>
          <p>Enter User ID: </p>
      <p><input type = "text" name = "nm" /></p>
      <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

waitingscreen.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content=
        "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Loader Bar</title>

    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #262626;
            font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
        }

        .loader {
            width: 150px;
            margin: 150px auto 70px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .loader .loading_1 {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 10px;
            border: 1px solid yellowgreen;
            border-radius: 10px;
            animation: turn 4s linear 1.75s infinite;
        }

        .loader .loading_1:before {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            width: 0;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: yellowgreen;
            box-shadow: 10px 0px 15px 0px yellowgreen;
            animation: load 2s linear infinite;
        }

        .loader .loading_2 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            top: 10px;
            color: green;
            font-size: 22px;
            text-align: center;
            animation: bounce 2s linear infinite;
        }

        @keyframes load {
            0% {
                width: 0%;
            }

            87.5% {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }

        @keyframes turn {
            0% {
                transform: rotateY(0deg);
            }

            6.25%,
            50% {
                transform: rotateY(180deg);
            }

            56.25%,
            100% {
                transform: rotateY(360deg);
            }
        }

        @keyframes bounce {

            0%,
            100% {
                top: 10px;
            }

            12.5% {
                top: 30px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="loader">
        <div class="loading_1"></div>
        <div class="loading_2">Please Wait...</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks :)

Comment: The code after your return statement is never reached. I think, out of the box flask doesn't support what you are asking for. You could use a web socket that updates the html when the scarping is finished. You may have a look at Flask-SocketIO for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the return statement ends the function in almost all languages.

say

```py
def func():
    print("hi")
    return 0
    print("after return")
func()
```

output:

```
hi
```

Whatever after return will not be executed (although see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262379/does-finally-always-execute-in-python) about `finally`).

In your context, you can try to preview "waitingscreen.html" on the frontend when you click the login button
and avoid rendering it from the backend.

Some simple JS will help.

refer: [Display a ‘loading’ message while a time consuming function is executed in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525029/display-a-loading-message-while-a-time-consuming-function-is-executed-in-flask)

Hope it will clear your query.